# How to use `Move to Front` option inside code?

Tags: graphics

I have a set of data with coordinate and a weight which I map with colours. I want a particular colour to appear on the top of others. For example

```
c[1] = Blue; c[2] = Red; c[3] = Green;
d1 = {RandomChoice[{1, 2, 3}], RandomReal[1, 2]} & /@ Range[20];
d2 = {RandomChoice[{1, 2, 3}], RandomReal[1, 2]} & /@ Range[20];
Graphics[{{c[#[[1]]], Disk[#[[2]], 0.1]} & /@ d1,
          {c[#[[1]]], Disk[#[[2]], 0.1]} & /@ d2}]
```

[image]

Now I want all the red points to appear on the top layer. Manually I can double-click on each of them and use `Move to Front` option.

[image] [image]

Is it possible to do it with a command?

Comment: They are rendered in the order that they appear inside of `Graphics`.

Comment: `FrontEndExecute[FrontEndToken["MoveToFront"]]` works. To test the code you can evaluate  `Button["x",FrontEndExecute[FrontEndToken["MoveToFront"]] ]`, select the disk, and click on the button.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Assuming your `Graphics` is saved in a variable `g`:

```
c[1] = Blue; c[2] = Red; c[3] = Green;
d1 = {RandomChoice[{1, 2, 3}], RandomReal[1, 2]} & /@ Range[20];
d2 = {RandomChoice[{1, 2, 3}], RandomReal[1, 2]} & /@ Range[20];
g = Graphics[{{c[#[[1]]], Disk[#[[2]], 0.1]} & /@ d1,
          {c[#[[1]]], Disk[#[[2]], 0.1]} & /@ d2}]
```

> [image: graphics]

Here is one simple way:

```
ReplacePart[g, 1 :> SortBy[Flatten[g[[1]], 1], First]]
```

> [image: graphics]

A drawback of this approach is that it reorders all the disks, not just puts red disks forward. The following approach only does the latter without reordering:

```
ReplacePart[g, 
 1 :> {Cases[g[[1]], {Except@Red, _Disk}, -3], Cases[g[[1]], {Red, _Disk}, -3]}]
```

> [image: graphics]

Answer (score 0):

I think the question is (at least partially) answered in a comment by @andre. (That is, use `FrontEndExecute[FrontEndToken["MoveToFront"]` on selected objects.)

An alternative way, following Alexey's approach, to move primitives with selected color to the front without changing the order of other primitives is to use `Pick`:

```
moveToFront[g_, color_: Red] := 
 Module[{prims = Join @@ g[[1]]}, 
  Graphics[Join @@ Pick[prims, #[[1]] === color & /@ prims, #] & /@ {False, True}]]

moveToFront[gr]
```

[image]

```
moveToFront[gr, Green]
```

[image]

where `gr = Graphics[{{c[#[[1]]], Disk[#[[2]], 0.1]} & /@ d1, {c[#[[1]]], Disk[#[[2]], 0.1]} & /@ d2}]`.

Comment: Of course, you would need more elaborate selection function in the second argument of `Pick`  for cases where the graphics directives and primitives are organized in arbitrary ways.